# getting index after compare or search

Tags: c#, gridview, indexing

I want to ask how to get the index

```
public void cari()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, myConnection);
            try
            {
                ds.Tables.Clear();

                command.Connection = myConnection;
                command.CommandText = "select * from General.genre WHERE genre Like  '%"+textEdit1.Text.ToString()+"%' or code like '%"+textEdit1.Text+"%'";
                myConnection.Open();
                //  adapter.Fill(dt);

                var  buka = command.ExecuteReader();


                if (buka.Read())
                {

                    var x1 = buka[1].ToString();
                    textEdit2.Text = x1;
                    MessageBox.Show("asdas" + textEdit2.Text + ";");


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("type genre");
                }
```

The above code only shows the string, but I want to know how to get the index. Maybe code inside after `if (buka.read())`?

[image]

Comment: Which index are you talking about? index for a given column name?

Comment: i forget to upload the image, if i type dance, it show 'dance' in what index

Comment: iam try to use the answer below it only display 1

Comment: What is the index ?

Comment: Do you mean the index of the row inside the SQL table ?

Comment: yes, index of the database SQL table

Comment: as you can see in ballet, is index of 1 is the code below before, and i got delete. he just using counter @@

Comment: Use the answer below to update your query and retrieve the original row number in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly advise you not to concatenate strings from UI input into SQL queries. This is highly prone from SQL-Injections. Instead use SQL Parameters.

**Solution:**

Use this SQL Query as your CommandText:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM " +
                "(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) [index] " +
                "FROM General.genre) R " +
                "WHERE [genre] LIKE '%" + textEdit1.Text.ToString() + "%' " +
                "OR [code] LIKE '%" + textEdit1.Text.ToString() + "%' ";
command.CommandText = query;
```

Then inside your read use:

```
var x1 = buka[1].ToString();
textEdit2.Text = x1;
var index = int.Parse(buka["index"]);
MessageBox.Show("asdas" + textEdit2.Text + "; Index = " + index );
```

Comment: hhm thanks for ur  reply. sure it works
but iam knda using that query. do you know how to display it?

Comment: @DavidChopperField You must change the query or you'll not get the original index int the table.

Comment: ok, want to make sure
why does the start of the index is 1 not 0 ?

Comment: you can add - 1 in your code or you query. Do what you please.if you want a zero-based result.

Comment: what does R stand for from "FROM General.genre) R  ?

Comment: Just an alias for the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code should give you the index corresponding to the column name.

```
int index = buka.GetOrdinal("ColumnName");
```

If you are using an index for accessing the fields of the reader you have the number required anyway.

Comment: but it only read what index is the column, i need for the row ?
like ballet.
thanks for the reply

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand that you want the row number.
But since this index is changing with every query, depending on where-statement and order by statement I guess you can only use an counter which you increment with every buka.Read();

Comment: is it like this ?
 int counter = 0;
MessageBox.Show("asdas" + textEdit2.Text + "; index of " + counter++);
the counter keep display as 0

Comment: Yes, it basically is like that. But since you do read only the first record of the DataReader (or did I miss a loop construction?) it will always be 0!
What exactly do you want to accomplish? Something like a relative record number in the table or do you need the 'sequence of arrival'?

Comment: i thinks its a relative record per index row.
i think its already solve with the answer above
thanks for replying